# Finding the residual of $\frac 1{e^z-1}$ at $z=2\pi ki$ using limits

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on finding $Res(f,2\pi ki)$ where $f(z)= \frac1{e^z-1}$. The example asks for me to use limits, which I know I can as $f$ has a simple pole at $2\pi ki$ for integers k, so I must take $\lim_{z\to 2\pi ki} (\frac {z-2\pi ki}{e^z-1})$. I was stuck at moving on from this step, and the solutions show the next step as simplifying it to $\lim_{z\to 2\pi ki} (\frac 1{e^z})$, and I can see why the residual is 1 from here. However, I'm struggling to see how $\frac {z-2\pi ki}{e^z-1}$ was simplified to $\frac 1{e^z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just apply L'Hopital's rule.